# How to create a "Fade in" effect of a String one by one letter at a time in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I'm trying to make textfield with the hintText having a fade effect of a String, this case it's "Please enter your password" I would like the fade affect to reveal the character of this String ("Please enter your password") one letter / character at a time, in sequential order. How would I go about doing this?

Here is a vid of what I'm trying to do:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9FZ6.jpg

I know how to make the whole String fade in and out together but I'm not sure how to make the fade animation of one character at a time in a string. Its like a fade in and shimmer effect but I've tried those and its not what I'm looking for

Comment: You can use this package. https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

Comment: @Arijeet and then use what?

Answer (score 0):

-- try to this code to create animation text.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FadingText extends StatefulWidget {
  const FadingText({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  final String text;

  @override
  State<FadingText> createState() => _FadingTextState();
}

class _FadingTextState extends State<FadingText> {
  late final AnimationController _controller;
  late final Animation<double> _opacityAnimation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      vsync: this,
    );
    _opacityAnimation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.easeIn,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _controller,
      builder: (context, child) => Opacity(
        opacity: _opacityAnimation.value,
        child: child,
      ),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Text(
          widget.text,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void startAnimation() {
    _controller.forward();
  }
}
```